# Decimal to Roman conversion program giving wrong answer in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to convert Decimal number to roman, but it is not printing correct answer for some numbers.

Here is my python code.

```
num = 600

d = {
    1: "I",
    4: "IV",
    5: "V",
    9: "IX",
    10: "X",
    40: "XL",
    50: "L",
    90: "XC",
    100: "C",
    400: "CD",
    500: "D",
    900: "CM",
    1000: "M",
}

t = 0
ans = ""
while num>0:
    for key in d.keys():
        if key < num:
            t = key
    num -= t
    ans = ans + d[t]

print(ans)
```

It prints `DXCIXIX` but the answer should be `DC`

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: Have you tried to find the cause of the wrong behavior?

Comment: Note: the iteration order of dicts wasn't guaranteed until rather recent Python versions…

Comment: 100 is not smaller than 100. So at least you need `key <= num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `key < num` with `key <= num`:

```
while num>0:
    for key in d.keys():
        if key <= num:
            t = key
    num -= t
    ans = ans + d[t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
roman = ""
for key in sorted(d.keys(), reverse=True):
    while num >= key:
        roman += d[key]
        num -= key
print(roman)
```

Comment: Or just use an ordered list of tuples and unpack: `for key, value in tuples`.